# Как создать карусель в друпале?

Tags: drupal

Добрый вечер всем, честно с друпалом (клиент захотел на этом) задолбался уже второй день, никогда не работал с ним и наче на своем давно уже сделал бы, во общем к каждой статье прикрепить карусель с картинками как в [этом](http://www.arendasib.ru/) сайте, уже устанавил несколько модульей, никаких изменений, статьей нормальных не нашел в инете, в самом друпал форуме никто не ответил, подскажите как это делается или скиньте источник, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На друпал.ру Вам никто не подскажет, ответы на все вопросы на оффсайте .org - первая ссылка http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel . )

Comment: О да, я установил этот модуль, опять же вопрос, как его прикрепить к статьям и я не вижу где настроить этот модуль

Comment: Либо при помощи Views (думаю в Вашем случае это лучший вариант), либо как любой Jquery плагин. http://drupalcode.org/project/jcarousel.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt  Всё предельно просто.

Comment: Вот модуль который решит Ваши проблемы без программирования. http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter  Просто скройте большое изображение {display: none} и всё.